# Where to create Angular modal Dialogs unrelated to controller (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

Where is the best place to create application or system-wide dialogs, which are unrelated to the current view controller / state?

For example: I am in a chat view and the system displays a (for example mdDialog) notification, that someone changed something in a completely different component.

Is it ok to use a Factory / Service for this, which will then open the Dialog?

I am asking, because this seems to be some kind of UI operation, which is usually done in a controller.

Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1):

For dialogs that are reused by multiple controllers, I think a factory is absolutely the right way to do this. For example, say you have a dialog that is for creating or editing individual widgets. It will be called from pages that already have a collection of widgets. I have something like this in my code right now:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngMaterial'])
        .factory('MyDialogsService', MyDialogsService)
        .controller('WidgetDialogController', WidgetDialogController);

function WidgetDialogController($mdDialog, Widget, WidgetService) {

    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
        Widget: new WidgetService.Widgets(Widget),      // ng-resource

        save  : save,
        cancel: cancel
    });

    function cancel() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    }

    function save() {
        vm.Widget.$save(null, function (output) {
            $mdDialog.hide(output);
        });
    }
}

function MyDialogsService($mdDialog) {
    return {
        openWidgets: openWidgetsDialog
    };

    function openWidgetsDialog(event, widget) {
        return $mdDialog.show({
            controller      : 'WidgetsDialogController as vm',
            templateUrl     : 'templates/widgets-dialog.html',
            bindToController: true,
            locals          : {Widget: widget},
            targetEvent     : event
        });
    }
}
```

This returns a promise so you can react to whatever happened in your dialog. In your controller, you can then use it like this:

```
function openWidgetDialog(event, item) {
    return MyDialogsService.openWidget(event, item).then(function (output) {
        vm.Widget = output;
        alert("Hey look a new widget!");
    });
}
```

...and your page template calls it with `vm.openWidgetDialog($event, theWidget)` or something. The `$event` gets passed around so that MD can open the dialog from the button with a nice animation. Anyway, this is basically what I use and it's worked pretty well.